# What is "Sock Puppet"? Does it mean "Sockpuppet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, spelling, hyphens, compounds

I've seen the word **Sock Puppet** used **[here](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet)**.

The page says to earn this hat: *ask and answer your own question, each with a score of 1 or more*.

Does this use of "Sock Puppet" actually mean "Sockpuppet"?

Comment: Begging for hats is unbecoming.

Comment: I sincerely thought it would be fun the first time I posted the question. But since the hat is irrelevant now, I think with a little nudge, this could be a good question in itself.

Comment: You can look up the meaning of the word in a dictionary. That being said, there is something to be said about compound words in English here.

Answer (score 2):

English is rather flexible when it comes to compound words. The concept of a puppet that has in some way a quality of a sock can be written “sock puppet”, “sock-puppet” or “sockpuppet”. Usually, the form with two words separated by a space indicates a looser coupling: this is the default way of combining two concepts. Joining the two words indicates a tighter coupling, and tends to be done when the compound takes a meaning of its own which isn't just the combination of the two meanings. Hyphenated compounds are rare in modern English; they used to be more common.

In other words, whether to write “sock puppet” or “sockpuppet” depends on whether the concept is that of a puppet that is a sock (“sock puppet” with a space: these are still two separate words) or the concept is a new one (“sockpuppet” as a single, new word).

Note that this is very gradual. When a concept is new, it is common to find both forms. Both forms are correct spellings. (All three even, with the hyphenated form, although the hyphen is less often used in modern English than it used to.) If a concept becomes well-established, the single-word form may become the standard spelling.

Take [*tree* + *house*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tree+house%2Ctree-house%2Ctreehouse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctree%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctree%20-%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctreehouse%3B%2Cc0) as example. There, the semantic coupling is loose: a *treehouse* is still a house that happens to be in a tree, so the spelling *tree house* remains common. The hyphenated spelling *tree-house* was once relatively popular but is now a minority.

For [*wall* + *paper*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wall+paper%2Cwall-paper%2Cwallpaper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwall%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwall%20-%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwallpaper%3B%2Cc0), the evolution went the other way. *Wallpaper* is not any wall-related paper, but a specific kind that is not made of the same material as writing paper. This explains why after a period when *wall-paper* was the most common spelling and a period when the three spellings coexisted, *wallpaper* became the standard spelling.

Some concepts have become so standard that they are clearly a word of their own and spelling. Although *housewife* was formed from [*house* + *wife*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+wife%2Chouse-wife%2Chousewife&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouse%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chouse%20-%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chousewife%3B%2Cc0), any other spelling would be considered wrong today.

[*Lap* + *top*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lap+top%2Claptop&year_start=1970&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clap%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claptop%3B%2Cc0) is another example. When the concept of a laptop computer was introduced, this was a computer that you could put on *top* of your *lap*. The spelling *lap-top computer* was common; the hyphen was used more often because *lap* characterizes *top* and [*lap* + *top*] characterizes *computer*. The concept of *a laptop* quickly became a new object (a *laptop* is not a kind of *top* at all); as a standalone concept, the word is now always written in a single word.

For *sock* + *puppet*, the [first meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet) is a kind of hand puppet (which itself is occasionally spelled *hand-puppet* or *handpuppet*), i.e. a puppet which consists of a decorated exterior over a hand. The decorated exterior is sock-shaped and is often an actual sock, hence the expression *sock puppet*. The meaning of the compound *sock puppet* is very close to “a puppet that is a sock”, so the form *sockpuppet* isn't used often. The compound took a second, metaphorical meaning: a [*sockpuppet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29) is someone who gives the impression of talking for himself, but is really controlled by another person. On the Internet, where nobody knows whether different user accounts are really different people, the word often means specifically a user account that belongs to the same person as another account. As this is a distinct concept (a *sockpuppet* in this sense would not be called a *puppet*), the single-word form is dominant (though using *sock puppet* is not wrong, just less common).

Answer (score -2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet),

> "A **sock puppet** is a puppet made from a sock or similar garment. The puppeteer wears the sock on a hand and lower arm as if it were a glove, with the puppet's mouth being formed by the region between the sock's heel and toe, and the puppeteer's thumb acting as the jaw. The arrangement of the fingers naturally forms the shape of a mouth, which is sometimes padded with a hard piece of felt, often with a tongue glued inside."

[image]

In my opinion, the use of Sock Puppet in this Winter Bash season would actually mean **[Sockpuppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29)**.

> A **sockpuppet** is an online identity used for purposes of deception. The term—a reference to the manipulation of a simple hand puppet made from a sock—originally referred to a false identity assumed by a member of an internet community who spoke to, or about, himself while pretending to be another person.

Anyway, one thing is certain for me, Sock puppets are irresistible!

[image: Many thanks to this photo's owner, Alex Brown!]
<sub>(Photo from [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/alexbrn/7919873782/))</sub>